# How can I add formatting punctuation to user input as they type text using Bash's "read" utility prompt?

Tags: linux, bash, punctuation

I have the following lines to prompt a user to enter a date/time that I use further down in my script:

```
printf "Please insert start of time window in format YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS: \n"
read startDatetime
```

Is there a way I can have the "read" prompt insert in the dashes for the date, the space between the date and time, and the colons for the time dynamically as a user types? I know this is possible using JavaScript on the web, but I am specifically looking for a command line version of that functionality.

I searched the web for an answer to this and cannot find one. I see an option for delimiter in the read Man Page but cannot see how it would achieve what I am trying to do.

Answer (score 2):

You can cobble it together by limiting the number of characters you read at a time using the `-N` flag for `read`:

```bash
echo "Please enter start time in YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS format"
read -rN4 year
printf '-'
read -rN2 month
printf '-'
read -rN2 day
printf ' '
read -rN2 hour
printf ':'
read -rN2 minute
printf ':'
read -rN2 second
echo

printf -v datetime '%s-%s-%s %s:%s:%s' \
    "$year" "$month" "$day" "$hour" "$minute" "$second"

echo "You entered $datetime"
```

Looks like this:

[image]

---

Alternatively, with the option to move the cursor back past the automatically added `-`, blank, and `:`: we can use `tput` to move the cursor, clear the line, and then use `read -e` (use readline for input) and `-i` (prefill prompt):

```bash
moveup=$(tput cuu1)
clearln=$(tput el)

echo "Please enter start time in YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS format"
read -rN4 datetime
printf '%b' '\r' "$clearln"
read -erN7 -i "$datetime-" datetime
printf '%b' '\r' "$moveup" "$clearln"
read -erN10 -i "$datetime-" datetime
printf '%b' '\r' "$moveup" "$clearln"
read -erN13 -i "$datetime " datetime
printf '%b' '\r' "$moveup" "$clearln"
read -erN16 -i "$datetime:" datetime
printf '%b' '\r' "$moveup" "$clearln"
read -erN19 -i "$datetime:" datetime

echo "You entered $datetime"
```

This isn't perfect, either: the extra characters are only inserted once, but not when you go back to fix something; and there's a newline inserted after the prompt that results in a blank line, which would be noticeable at the bottom of the terminal emulator:

[image]

At this point, you might consider using something like [charmbracelet/gum](https://github.com/charmbracelet/gum) for a very user-friendly interactive input experience at the terminal.

Comment: ...though one can't backspace to repair mistakes made in old fields, so while this does what the OP requested, I'm not sure it's a good idea.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Hmm, maybe with some tput magic to re-create the prompt in-place and `read -i` to pre-populate it 

Comment: Thanks so much for the solution Benjamin. This is functional enough and I will definitely incorporate this logic, but I agree a backspace option would be preferable. Any pointers on how a tput solution might work? Had a bit of a google but didn't see anything obvious.

Comment: @AWSnell I've added an attempt.